.NET 8 delegate* unmanaged throws Fatal error
I try to call manually mapped AOT-compiled .NET dll.
When i create delegate to function pointer and call it, it throws exception "Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code."
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate long AddNumbersDelegate(int a, int b);
    public static void Main()
    {            
      
        Memory Dll = new Memory(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\VsProjects\ClassLibrary1\bin\Release\net8.0\publish\win-x64\ClassLibrary1.dll"));           
        AddNumbersDelegate delegat = (AddNumbersDelegate)Dll.GetDelegateFromFuncName("Sum", typeof(AddNumbersDelegate));

        long val = delegat(40, 2); //fatal error Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code.\ works when AOT-compiled and .net framework 4.8
        
        Console.WriteLine("sum result:" + val);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


   public static void Main()
   {
       Memory Dll = new Memory(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\VsProjects\ClassLibrary1\bin\Release\net8.0\publish\win-x64\ClassLibrary1.dll"));
       IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)Dll.GetPtrFromFuncName("Sum");

       delegate* unmanaged[Cdecl]<int, int, long> delegat = (delegate* unmanaged[Cdecl]<int, int, long>)ptr;

       long val = delegat(40, 2); //fatal error Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code. \ works when AOT-compiled

       Console.WriteLine("sum result:" + val);

       Console.ReadKey();
   }

Dll(AOT-compiled):
 public class Class1
 {
     [UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Sum", CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl)})]
     public static long Sum(int a, int b)
     {
         return a + b;
     }

 }

Calling function pointer is 100% valid.
I tried many different things to solve it:

changing calling conversion
CallConvSuppressGCTransition
different types of delegates.

It works when i call it  with same code from .net framework 4.8 or AOT-compiled .net 8 exe, but throws error when i try to call from default-compiled .net 8 code. Doesnt matter debug or release. Also it works on .NET 8 when i try to call it with DllImport or LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress.

Well, it isn't actually wrong. Could you just remove the attribute? Or just use the function pointers directly rather than via a delegate?

it's AOT-compiled Dll(native). If i'll remove atribute i won't be able to call it. Also i dont know how to use pointers to function directly without delegat on c#.
I would be grateful for information on how to do this.

That it is AOT compiled does not make it native.  AOT merely does the job that the just-in-time compiler normally  does at runtime.  It is still managed code.

So i found the solution but i dont recommend to do it like me:
Exploring my process with x64dbg i figured out that this error throwed by AOT Dll. This is my called functionASM Sum func
If i replace this call instruction with nops it will work as expected returning sum of 2 int.
Other solution is follow this call and find first JNE instruction then patch it with JE
ASM security function
